# How do I delete unnecessary folders in my github repository?

Tags: github

How do I delete unnecessary folders in my github repository? The following is the github repository where I need to delete folders from: https://github.com/tux-superman/VitekSky

Comment: Important note: Git doesn't track folders. It tracks files. Remove the files and commit the change. It looks to me like you created a Git repository in the wrong location. In that case, it's going to be far easier for you to just create a new repo in the folder you actually want to commit to source control.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not exactly folders, but **gitlinks** (special [16000 entry in the index](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fast-import#Documentation/git-fast-import.txt-Inlinedataformat)): simple SHA1 entry referencing the root folder hash of another repository.

In your case, since there is no `.gitmodules` associated to said folders, all you need to do is:

```
git rm aFolder # no trailing /
git commit -m "remove aFolder entry"
git push
```

Answer (score 1):

Use git rm:

git rm file1.txt

git commit -m "remove file1.txt"

But if you want to remove the file only from the Git repository and not remove it from the filesystem, use:

git rm --cached file1.txt

git commit -m "remove file1.txt"

And to push changes to the remote repo

git push origin branch_name